# QGIS select first nth values from a sorted field

Tags: qgis

I have a point layer with a "dist" field. I need to show its value only for the lowest n features using the field calculator, Is there any function ready availalbe I am missing here?, like LIMIT in SQL for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if("dist"< array_get(
       array_agg(
          expression:="dist",
          order_by:="dist"),
       5),
       "dist",'')
```

it selects the first 5 features sorted ascending order